# Method Stubs in Java

Tags: java

This is what I have to do:

Define stubs for the methods called by the below main(). Each stub should print "FIXME: Finish methodName()" followed by a newline, and should return -1.

FIXME: Finish getUserNum()

FIXME: Finish getUserNum()

FIXME: Finish computeAvg()

Avg: -1

Here is the code that I have written so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MthdStubsStatistics {

public static int methodName (int userNum1, int userNum2, int avgResult) {
  System.out.println("FIXME: Finish getUserNum( )");
  System.out.println("FIXME: Finish getUserNum( )");
  System.out.println("FIXME: Finish computeAvg( )");
  System.out.println("Avg: -1");

return 0;

}

public static void main() {
  int userNum1 = 0;
  int userNum2 = 0;
  int avgResult = 0;

  userNum1 = getUserNum();
  userNum2 = getUserNum();

  avgResult = computeAvg(userNum1, userNum2);

  System.out.println("Avg: " + avgResult);

  return;
}
}
```

I can only edit the public static int methodName section. I thought I knew how method stubs operated, but I guess not. I swear that I am doing something wrong that is simple, but if someone could please help me out, that would be great.

Comment: This won't run, can you show us your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to define the methods `getUserNum()` and `computeAvg()`, but instead of having them do anything useful (for now) you should just have them return `-1` and print a message saying they need to be actually implemented. Since these methods don't actually do anything useful yet, they are called ["stubs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub).

The use of `methodName()` in the question is simply a placeholder for each method (as in method-name-goes-here). You should not define an actual method called `methodName()`.